# Button event in Gridview Footer template does not fire

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi all I gave placed the the button in the gridview footer template as below:

i also have handled the row command event but when i click on the button event does not fire

Comment: do you have an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

did u set the command name property for this button and check it in the code behind in the row command event ..

please put sample code to fix your problem.

Comment: Guys I got the solution. I place 2 grid control lets say grid1 and grid2. I handled the commond event of grid1 and i was checking grid2's commandName value in the grid1's command event that's why my button was not working. Thanks for the help